# How i can turn datetime to like "one minute age" in prisma node js graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, prisma

I'm trying to set the date time in Prisma migrate to human like one minute age, one month ago how I can manage to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Internationalization API [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) to do just that.

It would look something like:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en') // specify language here
console.log(formatter.format(-5, 'minutes')) // 5 minutes ago
console.log(formatter.format(5, 'months')) // in 5 months
```

Note that you need to specify the amount of time in English but if you change the language of the formatter, it will adapt the output to the specified language.

Of course you first need to calculate the amount of time first, but that shouldn't be difficult :)

Comment: how i can insert it in database using prisma?

Comment: You shouldn't. In database you should only store the date and time at which the operation was performed. Relative time cannot be stored otherwise, you would have to change its value every second that passes lol. The snippet I provided should be used in your frontend code.